# Notification of changes in files of a given type in a group of Github repositories

Tags: github, rss

I want to receive a notification (RSS, email, whatever) if anyone makes a change on any .md file in a Github repository. I have many repositories to watch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

https://app.github-file-watcher.com/ should do the trick - it monitors any public repo, and will notify you via email of changes to any file, a specific file, or some files that match your criteria.

Comment: 3 years laters, that looks interesting. +1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't natively proposed by GitHub:

- [The "notification mechanism" in place](https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars) ("watching a repo") is only for:

  - Issues and their comments
  - Pull Requests and their comments
  - Comments on any commits
- The [RSS feeds](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-your-feeds) are for your activities (like commits, but for all files)

You could setup a [Post-Receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) which would check what files are modified, and send an email.

Or you could use [Yahoo Pipe (as in this blog)](http://blog.chrismeller.com/get-your-github-issues-as-an-rss-feed) to monitor a particular file.